# Duplicate system symbols ASDF Common Lisp

Tags: build, lisp, common-lisp, asdf

If I'm using ASDF to build my Common Lisp system and have multiple projects in my ASDF path, how can I avoid naming collisions for my system names?

For example, if `project-a` and `project-b` both use a system `utilities` but they use different `utilities`, how can I make sure ASDF finds the correct `utilites` system?

I know that I could make utilities a directory instead of a system and reference individual files, but I find it desirable to use ASDF so I don't have to worry about specifying a path. Also, I'm trying to avoid a C-style  way of avoiding collisions, e.g., `project-a-utilities`.

Is there a typical convention here that I don't know about?

Comment: I don't really understand that part: "but I find it desirable to use ASDF so I don't have to worry about specifying a path". Could you explain what  problem you face with directories? would [ASDF modules](https://common-lisp.net/~mmommer/asdf-howto.shtml#sec9) help organize the utilities? do you expect to distribute the utilities without the projects? (if so, you need to define a different system for them with unambiguous names)

Comment: In my `.asd` file I can say that my system `:depends-on ("utilities")` rather than specifying the path to each source file in utilities that I will use. Perhaps modules would help. I don't know much about them. I'll do some research.

Comment: The more recent http://fare.tunes.org/files/asdf3/asdf3-2014.html documentation might help.

Comment: What is the advantage of using modules over simply referring to the files in order with serial enabled (`:serial t`)?